# Workflow Activity - Save Workflow Activity Name to a variable using the 'Assign' activity

Tags: c#, workflow-activity

I'm actually embarrassed to ask this question but here goes.

In a workflow activity, how do I get the name of the current activity?  For example, if I have a variable called "Name", how can I set that to the activity name.  I have tried:

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```

but it returns: "lambda_method"

My Google skills have failed today.

Here is an update, while debugging the Activity workflow, the watch windows says that 'this' is valid allows me to see the current activity name.  But when I try to use 'this' inside of the assign block on the Workflow activity, it throws a compile error:
Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "this.activity.displayName".
'this' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: I am looking for the activity name inside of a Workflow Activity.

Comment: I am trying to set a variable to the current activity name using an "Assign"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.activity.displayName` (which works in my Immediate Window when debugging a workflow)

Comment: Granted, that may be from the workflow context, not the activity context. YMMV

Comment: Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "this.activity.displayName".
'this' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I am trying to set a variable to the current activity name using an "Assign"

Comment: Try debugging the activity (right click and set a breakpoint) and looking through your Local variables for a string with the same name as your activity.

Comment: Interesting... My local variables and my watch windows shows that 'this' is valid.  But in my assign block, it won't let me compile.  Something is screwy

Comment: @user959729: The reason might be that the code in the assign block is a VB.NET expression. Try `Me` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString()
```

Comment: It returns the same: "lambda_method".  I am inside of a workflow activity... not in C# code.